# Reverse engineering NSDocument file

Tags: macos, cocoa, reverse-engineering, nsdocument

I have an unsupported file format from an OS X program. It uses `NSDocument`, unfortunately the vendor won't help with the format - or allow export.

So what are the first steps in reverse engineering this format based on `NSDocument`? 
The program still uses deprecated `initWithContentsOfFile` methods from os x 10.3.
I have access to the program, my data and lots of sample data.

I've done some initial work on disassembly of the program, and revese engineering the format. But haven't made much progress. The disassembly hasn't revealed a thing, but looking at the file with a hex editor has given me the outline of a few o the data structures and the initial fixed header.

Comment: If you have the program, why can't you just look at how it reads the file?

Comment: @jtbandes It sounds like he has access to the compiled program, not the source code.

Comment: Then I'm wondering how he knows it uses initWithContentsOfFile.

Comment: @jtbandes: I'm guessing the framework is probably logging deprecation warnings.

Comment: I've disassembled bits of the code with gdb which shows it. Also, an nm disassembly lists initWithContentsOfFile:ofType: as one of the methods in the program. I don't have the source, but the binary is not stripped.

Comment: For the record, the fact that the application uses `NSDocument` is irrelevant. Subclass of `NSDocument` must define their own format for document serialisation.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I've got my subclassed docFileFormat class. I still need help decoding that format.


Within the docFileFormat initWithContentsOfFile method disassembly there's some jumps inside the method (if/then's) and a few objc mach messages, along with iirc one superclass message.


Really, I'm trying to trace the loading code down to its lowest level then watch how it loads data/what it does with it. Then build up a format from there. Any recommendations on how I go about this?

Comment: class-dump will dump all the internal classes/structs from a binary into a header file. It's the same as tool -ov, but it dumps into an .h file.